# How to upgrade from xserver-xorg-lts-saucy to xserver-xorg-lts-trusty

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), and have upgraded xorg by installing `xserver-xorg-lts-saucy`.  I'd like to upgrade now to `xserver-xorg-lts-trusty`, but when I try `apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty` I get a whole lot of unmet dependencies:

```
 % sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-lts-trusty : Depends: xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty (>= 2:1.11) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed or
                                    xorg-driver-video
                           Depends: xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed or
                                    xorg-driver-input
                           Depends: xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: x11-xserver-utils-lts-trusty but it is not going to be installed
                           Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386 (>= 0~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have used `apt-mark showhold` to see held packages, and there are none.  Additionally I have tried to use aptitude to perform the upgrade instead of apt-get, but none of the suggested methods to resolve the conflicts looked sane to me.

What is the recommended way to upgrade from xserver-xorg-lts-saucy to xserver-xorg-lts-trusty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the correct way is to first fix the broken packages, so that you can remove it properly, before you install the new package.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

once it has installed all the missing dependencies, then run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

when it finishes, at this point you have two choices, manually remove the package you are having trouble with, or doing the full release upgrade, which is the recommended method.

so you can either go:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-lts-saucy
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty
```

or you can do:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

In the worst case scenario, if you already did upgrade to 14.04, but the xserver are still stuck on the old release for whatever reason, you can do this crazy move to remove all xserver files, so that you can re-install from the repositories.

sudo apt-get remove xserver*

doing that will also remove your Unity or Gnome, or whatever desktop environment you have installed, so you'll have to reinstall your choice of desktop environment, and that will automatically get you the missing xserver packages.

if you like the unity desktop do:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

or if you prefer the gnome desktop do:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-deskop
```

Comment: This was the closest to being correct.  For me the "sudo apt-get install -f" and "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" did nothing.  The important piece was to remove xserver-xorg-lts-saucy before installing xserver-xorg-lts-trusty, and then to reinstall ubuntu-desktop afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to upgrade the named packages together:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty \
    xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty \
    xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty \
    xorg-driver-video \
    xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty \
    xorg-driver-input \
    xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-trusty
```

If you get any errors about other packages with trusty in the name, add them to the list too.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I followed this approach and got to the point of having just one error: "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty : Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386
 xserver-xorg-lts-trusty : Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386 (>= 0~)"

Again, libglapi-mesa, is not held, and it isn't currently installed so that I can remove it.  Any ideas?

Comment: run `sudo apt-get upgrade --full-resolver`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

It might take a couple hours to download and install.

After you've upgraded to Ubuntu Trusty Tahr, try installing xorg again!

Good Luck!

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately this is a corporate environment and the 14.04 release is not available to me.