# Xorg 1.16 in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits

Tags: 14.04, xorg

I have installed de Xorg-edgers repository in Ubuntu 14.04, when I check the version It reply:

```
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux doceo-System-Product-Name 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-36-generic root=UUID=4b4277d8-18ea-4806-ab81-b5026822bab9 ro persistent quiet splash
Build Date: 30 July 2014  12:21:54AM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
```

I think the last version of Xorg is 1.16, is it possible install this version in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits now?

Note:I have the fglrx privative drivers for AMD/ATI HD 6700.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [xorg-server package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/xserver-xorg-core), version 1.16 will be shipped in 14.10 Utopic.

I don't think it will be available in Trusty, you might encounter some dependency issue if you try to install it on Trusty.

However, it's still possible to upgrade it. Please refer to this article:
[How to upgrade from xserver-xorg-lts-saucy to xserver-xorg-lts-trusty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496401/how-to-upgrade-from-xserver-xorg-lts-saucy-to-xserver-xorg-lts-trusty)

It's similar, as you're trying to upgrade from trusty to utopic.

Another solution is to install 14.10.

Comment: Thanks Well, I don't understand why the 1.16 version is not in Ubuntu 14.04, is a LTS version and 14.10 is a provisional version. I want install the last fglrx Gpu Drivers 14.09 and I know is risky make it using the package downloaded from website. Maybe I will try to do it or I will wait

Comment: I've tried the latest 14.9 Catalyst driver recently, they works well on my systems here. I think you will be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I install the fglrx privative drivers, the last version for Linux 64 is 14.301. in Ubuntu 14.04

I explain briefly:

I recommend to make a backup of your root partition or boot+root partition (I use REDO BACKUP)

1- Uninstall fglrx drivers installed in your system:

Open TERMINAL and write:

**fglrxinfo** (if you see the fglrx version then you have privative drivers installed, usually 13.35) if you don't see anything is possible you have free drivers.

Then write for uninstall driver:

**sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx***

2-REBOOT YOUR SYSTEM, then Ubuntu reboots using free drivers, if you write in TERMINAL: fglrxinfo, you cannot see any information

3-I use the software: ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/uaci/

4-Install sofware

5-Run UBUNTU-AMD-CATALYST-INSTALL from GRAPHIC TERMINAL:

**gksu**

write: **ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install**

Let the program install the driver and then reboot.

Voila: write in TERMINAL: **fglrxinfo**, you will see:

OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13084 Compatibility Profile Context 14.301.1001